# Removing multicast delegate based on return value

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have a class that has a multicast delegate:

```
class Signaler
{
  public delegate bool SomeAction(string s);
  public SomeAction Actors {get; set;}

  void SignalActors()
  {
    Actors("blah blah");
  }
}
```

What I would like to do is to have an actor removed from Actors when that actor returns false as part of handling its action. What would be a good way to do this in the `SignalActors()` function?

**Update**: Possible solution based on John Skeet's solution:

```
class Signaler
{
  public delegate bool SomeAction(string s);
  public SomeAction Actors {get; set;}

  void SignalActors()
  {
    SomeAction canceledSubscriptions=null;

    if (Actors!=null)
      foreach (SomeAction actor in Actors.GetInvocationList()) 
        if (!actor("Blah blah blah")) 
          canceledSubscriptions+=actor; 

    if (canceledSubscriptions!=null)
      foreach (SomeAction actor in canceledSubscriptions.GetInvocationList()) 
        Actors-=actor;
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't know what's your goal with this but it is a very unintuitive API. As a subscriber I wouldn't expect my subscription to be canceled this way.

Comment: Then, how as a subscriber would you cancel your subscription as part of processing a message? In other words, how would you signal as part of action processing that you are no longer interested?

Comment: by using the `-=` (unsubscribe) operator which is the inverse of the `+=` operator (subscribe): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms366768.aspx

Comment: I figured as much, as you can see from my update to the original question. I was hoping that maybe there was some framework already in place that could automate this use case (i.e., without having to go through the invocation list).

Comment: your update is not what I meant. You shouldn't add or cancel subscriptions in the SignalActors method. All that this method should do is invoke the subscribed methods. It is the the code that holds reference to this Signaler class that has to decide. Maybe I can't explain it very good. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is probably to actually build up a new delegate of all the ones that return `true`:

```
void SignalActors()
{
    SomeAction newActors = null;
    foreach (SomeAction actor in Actors.GetInvocationList())
    {
        if (actor("Blah blah blah"))
        {
            newActors += actor;
        }
    }
    Actors = newActors;
}
```

EDIT: The reason this is simpler than using `-=` is that it's obviously correct in terms of ordering. Whereas `+=` always adds to the end of the invocation list, `-=` also takes away from the end of invocation list... so if you remove actors in the *forward* order, you can have a problem. Suppose we have the following actors:

```
A - returns false
B - returns true
C - returns true
A - (duplicate of the first) returns true this time
```

You *should* end up with {B, C, A} but if you subtract A from {A, B, C, A} you'll end up with {A, B, C}. My approach avoids this problem.

Comment: But, let's say that unregistrations are very infrequent and it would be more efficient to build a list of "canceled interest" and then apply it to the delegate. That way the multicast delegate would not change, if there was no change in subscriptions. Would your patern still be the best way? Assuming, of course that there is another loop that applies the canceled registrations to the original Actor set.

Comment: @Michael: It sounds like you're micro-optimizing here. Do you have any evidence that the simple way isn't *efficient enough*? There are ordering problems with your second approach, which I'll go into in an edit.

Comment: I wasn't aware that delegates get removed from back to front. Fortunately, for my use case, I only have a single registration per delegate (guaranteed). The use case is parsing very large text files and sending each line of the file to interested parties. Parties may lose interest part of the way through the file (e.g., after processing the information they are interested in), short circuiting the file processing (e.g., if everybody unregisters during the processing of the file, stop processing the file).

Comment: It's a little more complicated than this, because a circular "prev line list" is maintained to hold the last N lines, before the current line, for context. This is why I want to try to avoid rebuilding the delegate list every line (of input), on the odd chance that an actor may lose interest at that line.

Comment: @Michael: In that case keeping track of the cancelled delegates would certainly work. It's probably worth commenting that if the assumptions around single registrations change, there are subtle issues waiting to pop up. Maybe at a link to this question :)

Comment: valid for delete delegate ? `Actors-=actor` ? `Delegate.RemoveAll method  or Actors=null`

Comment: @Kiquenet: I'm not sure what you're trying to ask in your comment. `Actors = null;` would set it to null, equivalent never having subscribed. `Actions -= actor;` just removes a single delegate.